# JetBrains Rider кодировка символов программы

Tags: кодировка, jetbrains, rider

При чистой установке программы не правильно отображаются символы, как исправить?
[image: etBrains]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось по умолчанию стоял битый шрифт, методом тыка исправил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]